# Null GetStringExtra (Intent) - Xamarin.Droid

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I am passing data from one activity1 to activity2 using intents. I consoled my data in activity1 and i am able to see the data that i am sending to activity2. But when i console the data i am receiving in activity2, i don't receiving any data. I have basically followed the right procedure in using intents but the trick isn't working.

**Question: Does async process affect the using of intents?**

**activity1**

```
private async Task GetData()
{
    var firebase = new FirebaseClient(FirebaseUrl);
    var items = await firebase.Child("TableName").OnceAsync<Person>();

    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        Person details = new Person();
        details.Name = item.Object.Name;
        person.Add(details);
    }

    void OnItemClick(object sender, int position)
    {
        Intent peaceHeroDetail = new Intent(this, typeof(PersonDetailActivity));
        Intent.PutExtra(PersonDetailActivity.EXTRA_NAME, person[position].Name.ToString());
        // the value of what is being sent is seen
        Console.WriteLine("This is selected person " +person[position].Name);
    }
}
```

**activity2**

```
public const string EXTRA_NAME = "Person Name";
string PName = Intent.GetStringExtra(EXTRA_NAME);
//it is empty
Console.WriteLine("This is the received detail "+ PName);
```

Comment: Could you please clean your code samples ? This is barely readable in my opinion

Comment: @yanyankelevich, hope it is quite better now.

Comment: Yep far better without a doubt

Comment: why are you initiating `peaceHeroDetail` as a new Intent but not using it? Plus, can you please show how are you opening second activity from first one?

Comment: @PaulKaram. I am using it. `StartActivity(PeaceHeroDetail);`. I only left it out so my code doesn't become so long.  That is basically how i am opeing my second activity from the first one, if you look at my activity2. I do that in the onCreate Method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your comment showed that it was a mistake, I deleted old answer and gave you this update.

**UPDATE**:

Check this following article: [Pass data between activities](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/fundamentals/activity/pass_data_between_activity/)

In your first activity, you should change this:

```
Intent peaceHeroDetail = new Intent(this, typeof(PersonDetailActivity));
Intent.PutExtra(PersonDetailActivity.EXTRA_NAME, person[position].Name.ToString());
```

to this:

```
Intent peaceHeroDetail = new Intent(this, typeof(PersonDetailActivity));
peaceHeroDetail.PutExtra(PersonDetailActivity.EXTRA_NAME, person[position].Name.ToString());
```

and then use : `StartActivity(peaceHeroDetail);`

Comment: Sorry about that error. It is actually a sample code and in my code, i have it exactly as you have your answer but it is not working

Comment: I just tried again taking out `ToString()`, i still get empty data

Comment: `ToString()` only references itself in a `String` object, it's not the problem. Check my last comment on your question, please share how are you opening second activity.

Comment: oh my bad..Thanks  a lot Paul